# What does the word "leggit" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, etymology, semantics

I've just finished Call of Duty Black Ops II, and there was one word whose meaning I couldn't find even on the Internet.

This is *leggit*, and it's a verb.

I have a link to a YouTube video with this cutscene:

https://youtu.be/-P5F8fzG42I?si=QRN0BvgyVnmo4tSu

Watch from 7:20 to 7:50.

So my question is: what does this verb mean?

P.S. I would like you to explain to me the etymology too, If this is not too hard for you, of course...

[image]

Comment: It's an AI generated subtitle. These can be very funny at times for the errors.

Answer (score 7):

That's just a bad spelling transcription of the verb [*to leg it*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/leg_it#English), which Wiktionary tells us is "slang" that means to run away or flee, or to hurry.

The OED dates it back to the 1500s, however, and does **not** call it slang at all.

> 1.a. *transitive*. to leg it.
>
> 1.a.i. ?1587– To travel or move by foot; to walk or (now esp.) run.

You really cannot take computer-generated anything at all seriously. It is not curated text.

Comment: It's curated and not computer-generated.  That's why I started wondering. But thank you for a comprehensive answer.